# Angular Material Table Page-Wise Selection: how to limit selection to the current page in Angular Material Table?

Tags: angular, angular-material

In Angular Material Table (with Pagination and Selection) when we click the checkbox in the header, it always selects all the rows. I there an easy way to select only the rows that are on the currently selected page?

Comment: Please provide feedback on my current solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4by7xt

Comment: It is doing same as i know.

Comment: This is allready the case in the stackblitz. If you add `<div>{{  selection?.selected | json}}</div>` in your html you can see this behaviour in action

Comment: Tim Martens, good idea for debugging, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use `$event.source.checked` to set value after define limit you want.[try my example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-suzvdb)